# Replacing dot by a comma and cast to double return null in Hive

Tags: hive, hql

Hello I need to replace **.(dot)** by a **comma(,)** in some column of materialized view in Hive and then cast it to **double/decimal** datatype.

My data look like : **11.1247653**

So I tried using :

```
SELECT CAST(regexp_replace('11.1247653','.',',') as double)
```

But, this return **NULL** values . Thanks for your help !

**Edit**

The expected result should be : **11,1247653** and it should has a **double** as datatype in the view.

Comment: data with a comma cant be of double data type. so i am not sure if the answer is possible. it internally always store as dot. so if you want to display as comma then the sql will be different.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is setting Locale in Hive. By searching through code I  did not see any support to changing Locale in Hive. However you can write your custom UDF to achieve this. But simply doing replace is easier

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to replace dot to cast to decimal. Hive follows `International Bureau of Weights and Measures` standards and uses dot for decimal point. so data is actually stored in dot.
so you should use below command.

```
CAST('11.1247653' as double) as out
```

if you have to display with a comma, then you can use replace to replace dot to comma.

Comment: Hello @Koushik Roy, thanks for your response but it does not change the datatype after replacing the dot by comma

Comment: can you pls clarify what is your expected result and data type?

Comment: data with a comma cant be of double data type. it internally always store as dot.